# Specificying a Page directive attribute on an NHaml page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhaml

I am working on an MVC site using NHaml for the view engine.

I have a page that needs to submit HTML code as a form value and am getting the System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException thrown at me.

I want to specify the <%@ Page validateRequest="false" %> so that this page will allow this data to be submitted but am unsure on how to do this with NHaml generating the pages.

Side note on this:
The editor I was using was TinyMCE and I found that it has an option for encoding the output, that way it doesn't trigger the anti-html validation.

Of course, then your value is encoded so you have to make sure to decode it at the proper time.

See http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try annotating your controller action with the [ValidateInputAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateinputattribute.aspx):

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // ...method body
}
```

This could also be done in the config file for the whole application:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <pages validateRequest="false" />
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I was aware of the global but didn't want to do that.

The attribute on the controller worked, thanks.

Comment: @ManiacZX, you are correct, putting this in web.config might represent a security risk because it will apply to all actions.